# Fix cloned Windows problems (laptop system-recovery, memtest, Windows recovery environment)

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, acer-aspire, disk-cloning, recovery

## Background/Cause

Several months ago, I upgraded my laptop's hard-drive to an SSD. The SSD is smaller than the hard-drive, so I freed up enough space for it to fit and cloned the drive to the SSD, with the only changes being that I shrank the laptop-recovery partition that contains the drive images from 15GB to 11GB and the system boot volume from 100MB to 50MB.

The system booted up just fine and I've been using Windows for the past few months without problem (at least no problems that can be attributed to the cloning/upgrade).

## Problem(s)

There is however one (technically three) problems that are likely due to the change:

1. <s>The memory test won't run and gives a `0xc000000e` error about `memtest.exe`.</s>
2. Windows Repair won't run and gives a `0xc000000f` error.
3. The (Acer) laptop's system recovery function won't run from pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> (I double- and tripled-checked the BIOS setting that could prevent it from working).

## Mitigation Attempts

I created a Windows Recovery DVD from within Windows and used that to access the Windows Repair environment and it complained about a problem and fixed it. I rebooted into the Recovery environment and ran `bootrec` with the `/scanos`, `/fixboot`, `/fixmbr`, and `/rebuildbcd`.

## Results

Now the memory test works!  One down, two to go.

## Problems - Redux, Reprise, Part II, *The Return*

Unfortunately, pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> to access the boot menu and selecting Repair still gives a `0xc000000f` error and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> still won't bring up the system-recovery D2D program.

I suspect the former problem has something to do with the `C:\Recovery` folder, but it looks intact, so I don't know why Windows is unable to load `WinRE.wim` from it. I don't think it's a matter of permissions.  I can only think that maybe the BCD isn't correct, but I can't find any information on fixing it (all the pages that come up when doing a web-search say to boot into the recovery environment, but that's what won't load, and the stuff they say to do, I already did from the one that I booted from DVD).

As for the Acer system-recovery, I assume that's got to do with the recovery partition being smaller than it used to be and/or the offset having changed. The partition is there and the files are accessible (I can assign a drive-letter in Windows and access them), but the BIOS program might not be seeing it. Could it be hard-coded to look for the partition at a specific sector  (and thus be a colossal bit of bad coding ¬_¬)?

## Resources

This isn't my system; it's the only "screenshot" I could find related to the Acer D2D system-recovery function. In my BIOS, there are two settings that could block it, one is simply setting it as enabled or not, and the other is setting is the SATA mode, both of which are correct, so the hotkey *should* be launching the D2D program on reboot (it used to work when it was the hard-drive).

[image: Acer D2D System Recovery Option in BIOS]

---

Here's my BCDEdit status. It's pretty normal (looks almost identical to other ones I can find). (Note, the GUIDs are irrelevant and the driver-signing flags are not related.) The only difference is that Windows is loading from volume 2 instead of 1, but that's correct; volume 0 is the laptop recovery partition, volume 1 is the system boot volume, and volume 2 is C:. What's strange is that there's no mention of the recovery environment in there, but I don't see it in screenshots of other people's systems either. I could have sworn BCDs used to contain a reference to it.

[image: BCDEdit]

Comment: Need to know your boot order in bios and Boot and system drive volumes in disk manager

Comment: The SSD. That's it. I took the DVD drive out. (And of course, I took the hard-drive out after cloning it.)

Comment: (I've fixed the built-in Windows RAM-test function—by replacing `memtest.exe` with an old copy, and also fixed the Windows repair function—iirc, by using the `reagentc` command. Now I only need to figure out how to fix the Acer system-recovery function. If I can get a new SSD to transfer the system to it again, I'll try resetting the partition size of the recovery partition—which wastes 4GB of empty space—and see if that works.)